# search with async source (Angular2 promise)

Tags: search, asynchronous, angular, promise, semantic-ui

I'm using [Search](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html) component of `Semantic-UI` and Angular2 promise.
Here is my code:

**foo.component.ts**:

```
export class FooComponent implement OnInit {
    myData:any = [];
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myDataService.getData().then(myData => this.myData = myData);
        $('.ui.search').search({ source: this.myData });
    }
}
```

**foo.component.html**:

```
<div class="ui search">
    <input class="prompt" type="text">
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

But `source` is always empty. I think this happens due the async call to the data service.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Answer from fstanis is technically correct. But I have a little addition to what he missed. The OP was keeping the results in a component level property and not directly using the returned result, may be for later use. I'm also adding to this answer one more possible way of achieving this.

## 1) The way OP was trying to do it

```
export class FooComponent implement OnInit {
    myData:any = [];
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myDataService.getData().then(myData => {
            this.myData = myData;
            $('.ui.search').search({ source: this.myData });
        });
    }
}
```

## 2) Using Angular 2 Subscribe

```
export class FooComponent implement OnInit {
    myData:any = [];
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myDataService.getData().subscribe(
            data => {
              this.myData = data;
              $('.ui.search').search({ source: this.myData });
            },
            error => {
              // Write your logic here if an error was occurred. Use the variable "error" which has info about what happened.
            },
            () => {
              // This fires when the call has been finished. Just like .complete in jQuery.get or jQuery.post. So that you can do necessary operations after everything is completed.
            }
        );
    }
}
```

## This is how your service should look like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MyDataService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getData(){
    return this.http.get('some/api/url').map(
        res => res.json()
    );
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but both solutions don't work. The search popup is empty.

Comment: Did you check to see if your angular 2 service is correctly fetching the data from the server? Let me update my answer to include a sample of how the service should look like.

Comment: It works using `mockResponse` of Semantic-UI search component.

Comment: Your solution use `Observable` instead of `Promise`.

Comment: Well, I did provide multiple ways of achieving your end result.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're initializing the search with the initial value (an empty array) since the data hasn't arrived yet when ngOnInit is ran.

The easiest solution for this particular case is to just wait for your data to arrive before initializing the search component:

```
export class FooComponent implement OnInit {
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myDataService.getData().then(myData => {
            $('.ui.search').search({ source: myData });
        });
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that Semantic UI's search component has a built-in mechanism for keeping search results remote - you might want to check it out in the [usage section of the docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/usage) to see if you can utilise that instead.

Comment: I did read that link in the docs, but i can't figure out how to apply the "Angular2 way" (the promise) to the search component. Can you help me?